# Join two tables or select queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to join two tables and get the output as i stated below,
[image]

Here my problem is I couldn't inner join the two tables and get the output since it refers the same column name for team1 and team2 (Which will look like "select ct.teamname,ct2.teamname from clm_schedule cs" where it gives me an error). I can do it in two separate queries like below,

```
select ct.teamname as team1 from clm_schedule cs inner join clm_team ct on ct.teamid = cs.team1

select ct2.teamname as team2 from clm_schedule cs2 inner join clm_team ct2 on ct2.teamid = cs2.team2
```

But I couldn't join it to get a single resultset. Please suggest me a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
SELECT ct1.teamname as team1 ,ct2.teamname as team2 
FROM clm_schedule cs 
LEFT JOIN clm_team AS ct1 
  ON ct1.teamid = cs.team1
LEFT JOIN clm_team AS ct2
  ON ct2.teamid = cs.team2;
```

Comment: AgRizzo, I think you are right, but on the last line it should be "cs.team2" right?

Comment: hehe :D thanks.. tried to edit it on your answer but it doesn't allow me to i guess